# Copy text from JTextField to JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, text, jtextfield, jtextarea

Why can't I copy the text from a `JTextField` to a `JTextArea`? `orders` is a `JTextArea` and `get` is a `JTextField`. Status is `JButton`.

class client:

```
  public client() extends superclass{
        super("CLIENT");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        update = new JLabel("status");
        add(update,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        order = new JPanel();
        add(order,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        menu = new JList(kveb);
        menu.setVisibleRowCount(8);
        menu.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        add(new JScrollPane(menu));
        get = new JTextField("chaweret rac gsurt");
        add(get);
        status = new JButton("ORDER!");
        status.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,16));    
        add(status);
        guga k1 = new guga();
        menu.addListSelectionListener(k1);
        get.addActionListener(k1);
        status.addActionListener(k1);
        server tes = new server();
        tes.setSize(300,300);
        tes.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        tes.setVisible(true);
    }
```

class server:

```
public class server extends superclass{
    public server() {
        super("SERVER");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        // public JCheckBox ready;
         // public JCheckBox working;
         // public JCheckBox ordered;
          //public JCheckBox trans;
        //  public JTextField orders;
        ready = new JCheckBox("text");
        ready.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,16));
        add(ready);
         Font x = new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,16);
         working = new JCheckBox("text here");
         working.setFont(x);
         add(working);
         migebulia = new JCheckBox("text heere");
         migebulia.setFont(x);
         add(migebulia);
         trans = new JCheckBox("mtext");
         trans.setFont(x);
         add(trans);
         orders = new JTextArea("text");
         orders.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,16));
         add(orders);
         guga k2 = new guga();
         ready.addActionListener(k2);
         working.addActionListener(k2);
         ordered.addActionListener(k2);
         trans.addActionListener(k2);
        // orders.addActionListener(k2);    
    }    
}
```

super class:

```
public class superclass extends  JFrame {
      //client
      public JList menu;
      public  JTextField get;
      public JPanel order;
      public JButton status;
      public String kveb[] = {"text","texti","text","text"};
      public JLabel update;
      //server
      public JCheckBox ready;
      public JCheckBox working;
      public JCheckBox ordered;
      public JCheckBox trans;
      public   JTextArea orders;

    public superclass(String string) {

    }

    class guga implements ActionListener, ListSelectionListener,DocumentListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            if(event.getSource() == status){
                event.setSource(get);
                 orders.setText(get.getText());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when this piece of code gets executed? Do you get text at all in the `JTextArea`? What does `get.getText()` returns?

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: get is JTexTfield,status is JButton orders is textArea , I want that when I type  something in JTextField it must 'copied' in JTextArea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to copy the text only when the button `status` is hit, then you can do:

```
status.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent pE) {
        orders.setText(get.getText());
    }
});
```

If you want to copy from Server Frame to Client frame or the opposite, you need to pass destination component to parent class in constructor:

```
JTextArea destTextArea;
public superclass(String string, JTextArea pDestTextArea) {
    destTextArea = pDestTextArea;
}
....
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    if ((event.getSource() == status) && (destTextArea != null)) {
        destTextArea.setText(get.getText());
    }
}
```

Then to create your Client and Server:

```
super("CLIENT", null);
super("SERVER", orders);
```

or:

```
super("CLIENT", orders);
super("SERVER", null);
```

Comment: but I want when I press status JButton to copy it, I tried ActionListener but its not working!

Comment: its not working maybe because I got two classes but I am using inheritance so what I have to Do JtextField is in other class and JTextArea is in another class.

Comment: So I guess you need to post more code if you want some further help on how to make it work on your application...

Comment: Oh, your need was not very clear then. Do you need to copy from Server to Client? (or the opposite). Is that the idea?

Comment: If you need to copy from Server to Client or the opposite, then you need to add getter for your JTextField and JTextArea so that the code (not shown here) that creates Server and Client can get the TextField of one and put its content in the JTextArea of the others using the new getters.

Comment: sorry, it doesn't work :D and it doesn't show up any errors too, I don't what to do, I have head ache with trying to do this code :((

Comment: You're comparing objects with `==` instead of `equals()`.

Comment: @user1803551 IMO it is safe to compare the *reference* of these objects here, instead of comparing the objects

Comment: @user3593130 I understand, I also had head ache with your code, but there's nothing impossible there... just read carefully all we have said here, and build something with the code I posted, you may need some light arrangements though

Comment: @xav The reference might not be the same. `getSource()` creates an undeclared instance of a `JComponent` and you want it to be the same as the already declared `JButton` reference? `equals()` will always work correctly.

Comment: @user3593130: I do not agree, `getSource()` does not create *"an undeclared instance"*. You can check it with a simple `System.out.println(btn == e.getSource());`  ==> it is always printing `true`.  The `ActionEvent` is set up with the real reference of the source component, not another instance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the structure of your application is, but try to merge what I post here with your current code with the least changes you can. Once it works you can start moving things around.

Client class:

```
public class Client {

    public JTextField get = new JTextField("chaweret rac gsurt");
    public JButton status = new JButton("ORDER!");

    Client() {

        status.addActionListener(new Superclass.MyListener());
    }
}
```

Server class:

```
public class Server {

    public JTextArea orders = new JTextArea("text");
}
```

Superclass class:

```
public class Superclass {

    static Client client = new Client();
    static Server server = new Server();

    public static class MyListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (e.getSource().equals(client.status))
                server.orders.setText(client.get.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

Note: class names should start with an uppercase letter according to Java conventions.

Comment: If what you're trying to do is copy the text when a button is pressed then use `ActionListener`.

Comment: class k1 implements ActionListener, {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
   if(event.getSource() == status){
    String geti = get.getText();
    orders.setText(geti);
   }
  }